# use tabs in a class that extends Fragment

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

Usually tabs are used inside a class that extends FragmentActivity.

My problem is that i'm using a NavigationDrawerFragment where for every voice of the left menu you click, it open a new fragment. 
So i need to have the tabs in a fragment (a class that extends Fragment). 
It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add a ViewPager inside that fragment using ChildFragmentManager with as may fragments you want.

Comment: can u give me a simple example please?